# Line Break in Programming

Tags: c, file-io, newline

Using `\n` represents line breaks in all programming languages I know of. But when it is used to write string to txt file, there is either \n written or replaced by some symbol or other element **when viewed under notepad.**. But other text editors such as Notepad++, Kate etc display fine.

What is the reason for this discrepancy?

Can I make the program  e.g. C to write line breaks so that notepad itself displays as line break and not some symbol in between?

P.S. Everyone should have experienced this sometime in programming life. Who used windows.

Comment: Read up on text files vs binary files, and CRLF vs NL line endings.  It sounds as though you're writing files with Unix (NL) line endings and Notepad is not interpreting them as you'd like because it expects Windows (CRLF) line endings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need a `\r\n` for Notepad in windows.  Notepad++ and Kate are far better editors that are `\r\n` and `\n` aware and display the line break as you would like, or as you configure them.

Comment: Even Wordpad handles line endings better, if you don't have a decent programming editor installed.

Comment: Ironically, Notepad supports Unicode encodings and Wordpad supports non-CRLF newlines, but there is no pre-installed program on Windows that supports both.

Comment: Note that when writing files opened in text mode, the C Run-Time library automatically translates `\n` into platform-appropriate line breaks (which means `\r\n` on Windows). Opening a file in binary mode suppresses this translation.